# Can't pass "Revocation" check in pdf Adobe Reader

Tags: pdf, adobe, digital-signature

I am building my CA, everything seems Ok, but when I signed PDF with my child certificate, I got a warning in Adobe PDF Reader at "Revocation" tab to show:

[image: Revocation]

I did setup CRL URI (Revocation List) in my child certificate, and I can access the URI by web browser.

I added the root certificate (issuer) into the trust anchor.

Does anyone have any idea why I can't verify CRL list?

Comment: Please share a sample PDF signed by a signer certificate of your CA. If necessary, please also share otherwise unknown relevant certificates.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer, it took me 3 days to identify the issue.

The issue related with my CRL file, the begin/tag I wrote is:

```
-----BEGIN CRL-----
-----END CRL-----
```

Actually, Adobe PDF Reader/Acrobat expects:

```
-----BEGIN X509 CRL-----
-----END X509 CRL-----
```

Hope it can help other one with the same issue.

Comment: Hi Box Very, I m facing this issue, did you embed the CRL? Can you share the code on how you integrate CRL within your Pdf? Many thanks